# Infowindow that follows mouse with Google Maps JS v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

It is possible to create an infowindow that follows the mouse? Preferably offset to the top right of the mouse pointer.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = 'follow mouse';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this at the end of the initialize() function makes the infowindow follow the mouse.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(event){
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
});
```

Adding the param pixelOffset to the infowindow function offsets it top right.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10,-10)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for "pixelOffset", it saved my day :)